# wordpress extended_valid_elements for script tag?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

Can someone tell me how to tell Wordpress' tinymce editor to NOT strip out script tags?  I looked in `wp-admin/includes/post.php` and added

```
'extended_valid_elements'=>'script[charset|defer|language|src|type]',
```

to the `$initArray`.

When I do a view source on the CMS post editor, I see that it does show up like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
tinyMCEPreInit = {
    base : "http://dev.esolar.ca/wp-includes/js/tinymce",
    suffix : "",
    query : "ver=327-1235",
    mceInit : {
        mode:"specific_textareas", 
        editor_selector:"theEditor", 
        width:"100%", 
        theme:"advanced", 
        skin:"wp_theme",
        theme_advanced_buttons1:"bold,italic,strikethrough,|,bullist,numlist,blockquote,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,link,unlink,wp_more,|,spellchecker,fullscreen,wp_adv", 
        theme_advanced_buttons2:"formatselect,underline,justifyfull,forecolor,|,pastetext,pasteword,removeformat,|,charmap,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,wp_help", 
        theme_advanced_buttons3:"", 
        theme_advanced_buttons4:"", 
        language:"en",
        spellchecker_languages:"+English=en,Danish=da,Dutch=nl,Finnish=fi,French=fr,German=de,Italian=it,Polish=pl,Portuguese=pt,Spanish=es,Swedish=sv",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location:"top", 
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align:"left",           
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location:"bottom", 
        theme_advanced_resizing:"1", 
        theme_advanced_resize_horizontal:"", 
        dialog_type:"modal", 
        relative_urls:"", 
        remove_script_host:"", 
        convert_urls:"", 
        apply_source_formatting:"", 
        remove_linebreaks:"1", 
        gecko_spellcheck:"1", 
        entities:"38,amp,60,lt,62,gt", 
        accessibility_focus:"1", 
        tabfocus_elements:"major-publishing-actions", 
        media_strict:"", 
        paste_remove_styles:"1", 
        paste_remove_spans:"1", 
        paste_strip_class_attributes:"all", 
        wpeditimage_disable_captions:"", 
        plugins:"safari,inlinepopups,spellchecker,paste,wordpress,media,fullscreen,wpeditimage,wpgallery,tabfocus"
    },
    load_ext : function(url,lang){
        var sl=tinymce.ScriptLoader;
        sl.markDone(url+'/langs/'+lang+'.js');
        sl.markDone(url+'/langs/'+lang+'_dlg.js');
    }
};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

But for some reason ,my editor still doesn't save `<script>` tags.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with iframes.  I think instead of `<script attributes>`, it might be `[script attributes]`.   You'll have to look up the syntax

Answer (score 5):

It's down to [KSES](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses) filtering before your post is saved in the DB.

In your theme's functions.php, globalise the variable `$allowedpostags`, then add the tags you want to allow like so;

```
 global $allowedposttags;
 $allowedposttags['script'] = array(
     'type' => array(),
     'src' => array()
 );
```

Note the structure of the array, and the fact you have to specify the allowed attributes too.

Comment: but the tags are stripped out immediately after I press Publish in the wysiwyg editor.  I click on the HTML tab in the editor, and the <script> tags have been removed from the content.

Comment: So, let me just make sure I get you - you type some `<script>` in the HTML editor, switch to TinyMCE, switch back and it's gone?

Comment: almost...click on HTML of the editor, type <script>stuff</script>, press publish, page refreshes, the <script> tags disappear from the editor.